# How to bind into map with multi ViewModelFactory using Dagger2

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger, android-architecture-components

I tried to follow the example of the google([ViewModelModule](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/di/ViewModelModule.java)). And I saw it can bind to different ViewModel type to the generic one.

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(UserViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindUserViewModel(UserViewModel userViewModel);

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(SearchViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindSearchViewModel(SearchViewModel searchViewModel);

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(RepoViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindRepoViewModel(RepoViewModel repoViewModel);

    @Binds
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(GithubViewModelFactory factory);
}
```

What I want to do is to bind multi ViewModelProvider.Factory to the generic one.

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {


  @Binds
  @IntoMap
  @ViewModelFactoryKey(FeedEntryListViewModelFactory.class)
  abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(FeedEntryListViewModelFactory factory);

}
```

ViewModelFactoryKey.java

```
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
@interface ViewModelFactoryKey {
  Class<? extends ViewModelProvider.Factory > value();
}
```

FeedActivity.java

```
public class FeedActivity extends DaggerAppCompatActivity {


  @Inject
  ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;

  FeedEntryListViewModel viewModel;


  @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
  }
}
```

However, it throws the following error.

```
Error:(21, 8) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.Factory is injected at
com.cn29.aac.ui.feedentry.FeedActivity.viewModelFactory
com.cn29.aac.ui.feedentry.FeedActivity is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
```

I am new to Dagger2. If it is not used properly, please feel free to comment. Thank you.

Comment: `What I want to do is to bind multi ViewModelProvider.Factory to the generic one` - what does this mean? You have various factories, and you want to put them into a map?

Comment: Yes, I want it. Actually I have multi classes FeedListViewModelFactory,FeedDetailViewModelFactory ... But in these Activities , the injected type is ViewModelProvider.Factory . Therefore, I need to map both to the ViewModelProvider.Factory.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change following:

```
@Inject
ViewModelProvider.Factory viewModelFactory;
```

To this:

```
@Inject
Map<Class<? extends ViewModelProvider.Factory>, Provider<ViewModelProvider.Factory>> viewModelFactoriesMap;
```

Comment: Can't I inject Factory instead of Map in the Activity class?

Comment: In [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46601474/how-to-bind-into-map-with-multi-viewmodelfactory-using-dagger2/46603759?noredirect=1#comment80155960_46601474) you told, that you want to put your factories into a map. What exactly do you want now? Which factory do you expect to be injected?

Comment: Oops, Sorry for my bad reply. I would like to have the Factory injected only, not the mapping. Nvm, now I thought I have confused on the generic injection on dagger2. Anyway, thx for your help.

Comment: If you specify your question precisely I will try to answer it. Which viewmodel do you want to be injected? If your question is resolved, let me know.

Comment: @azizbekian How would we inject `FeedEntryListViewModelFactory`?